Firebase Notifications: onMessageOpenedApp Not Triggering When Clicking Notification in Flutter
I've been working on integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with my Flutter app, and I've run into an issue where the onMessageOpenedApp method is not triggered when I click on a notification while the app is in the background or terminated.
Here's my setup:
Main Dart File (main.dart)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'my_app.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Home Screen Dart File (home_screen.dart)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'firebase_messaging_service.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FirebaseMessagingService notificationServices = FirebaseMessagingService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notificationServices.requestNotificationPermission();
    notificationServices.foregroundMessage();
    notificationServices.firebaseInit(context);
    notificationServices.setupInteractMessage(context);
    notificationServices.isTokenRefresh();
    notificationServices.setupFirebase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Flutter Firebase Messaging Demo'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Firebase Messaging Service Class (firebase_messaging_service.dart)
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'communication_view_model.dart';

class FirebaseMessagingService {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void isTokenRefresh() async {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      debugPrint("Token refreshed: $event");
    });
  }

  Future<void> setupFirebase() async {
    messaging.getToken().then((value) {
      debugPrint("FCM Token: $value");
    });
  }

  void initLocalNotifications(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iosInitializationSettings,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (response) {
        handleMessage(context, message);
      },
    );
  }

  void firebaseInit(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Notification Title: ${notification?.title}");
        print("Notification Body: ${notification?.body}");
        print('Data: ${message.data}');
      }

      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        foregroundMessage();
      }

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        initLocalNotifications(context, message);
        showNotification(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('User granted permission');
      }
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('User granted provisional permission');
      }
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('User denied permission');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      channelDescription: channel.description,
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.high,
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
    );

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        message.notification?.title,
        message.notification?.body,
        notificationDetails,
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> setupInteractMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        print("Initial message received: ${message.data}");
        handleMessage(context, message);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessageOpenedApp triggered with message: ${message.data}");
      handleMessage(context, message);
    });
  }

  void handleMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    // Handle the message
  }
}

Android Manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="your_app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/green"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>

Issue
I am receiving notifications when the app is in the background.
Clicking on the notification does not trigger the onMessageOpenedApp method.

What I've Tried
Verified that the notification payload includes click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK".
Added intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml for FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK.
Initialized Firebase in main.dart and set up background message handler.
Used FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin to show notifications.

Question
How can I ensure that onMessageOpenedApp is triggered when a notification is clicked while the app is in the background or terminated?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
